# Adjusting size of plot in R

Tags: r, image

I have a distribution plot that I want like this:

```
dev.new(width=5,height=2)
plot(w.count.v, main="Distribution Plot of 'she' in Two Kinds",xlab="Novel Time",ylab=m=c(0,1),yaxt="n")
```

[image]

How do I save it as a `.png` as the size on the device? When I save it, this is the resulting image.

[image]

Comment: you can specify `width` and `height` in the paramters of `dev.copy`

Comment: Or if you save using `png` you can set the aspect ratio by specifying the width and height in pixels. For example: `png("file.png", width=600, height=150); plot(1:10,1:10); dev.off()`.